# Is there a way to delete cells if their value is contained in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns with a few thousand rows and I would like to find the cells that are common across all columns. Is there a function that I can use to check if a cell value exists in a set of cells/column?

Comment: Common within the same row or any row as long as it's in all columns?

Comment: If you have datain cols A-C then in D1 just go `=AND(A1=B1, A1=C1)` and now you can filter on col D

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear. The row doesn't matter. As long as the value is in one cell of all columns it should not be deleted. If it's easier I could create the result (all cells in common) as a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if a value exist in all columns but in any row you can put this equation in the next open column and drag down:

```
=AND(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),MATCH(A1,C:C,0))
```

This assumes you have data in column A, B & C and the equation is in column D.  now you can sort on column D for unique values.

[image]

---

Depending on your data type you might get an error.  If that is the case try this:

```
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),FALSE),IFERROR(MATCH(A1,C:C,0),FALSE))
```

Comment: I feel like this should be exactly what I need, but when I try to implement it myself I get a result of #N/A for the matches which then leads to #N/A for the AND. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now. Out of curiosity, do you know why it returns an error when there is no match?

Comment: Good question: I did a quick look at MS doc and found that #N/A is default return value when your looking for an exact match.  Seems like 'false' would have been a better choice.

Comment: That would make much more sense. I appreciate the help and thanks for answering my question.